# codeigniter 3 size of form_upload

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation, upload, filesize

I work on Codeigniter 3 and i have one form for upload one file-zip, my form does a good job on small zip, but i must upload some file between 5 and 15 Mo, the form doesn't work and i haven't error.

I have see in *Librairies/Form_validation/* *run()* of CI, and the first condition crash :

```
// Do we even have any data to process?  Mm?
$validation_array = empty($this->validation_data) ? $_POST : $this->validation_data;
if (count($validation_array) === 0)
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

I have set my server on file for 20Mo, time of input 60sec, I have try the HTML *"MAX_FILE_SIZE".*

Have you one idea on my problem ?

Comment: What is your upload config ? see $config['max_size']             = 10000;